# Why jQuery blocks page rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

I have some questions about page rendering. Here is my html code:

```
<body>
   <h1>haha</h1>
   <img src="a.jpeg" alt="images1">
   <img src="b.jpeg" alt="images2">
   <script src="public/js/doSomething.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</body>
```

And my `doSomething.js` takes 5 seconds to execute:

```
function doSomething(n){
     var start = new Date().getTime() ;
     while((new Date().getTime() - start) < 1000 * n){}
}
doSomething(5) ;
```

I put `<script>` tag in the end of `<body>` so that the other elements will show before `doSomething.js` loads. But my page turns out yielding nothing until `doSomething.js` finishes executing.

And if I removes jQuery script, the other DOM elements(`h1` and `images`) will be shown successfully before `doSomething.js` loaded.

Here are my questions:

1. Why jQuery blocks DOM rendering in my example?
2. If I remove jQuery, and everything works as my expectation, then I get another question. In my understanding, `<script>` is part of DOM tree, and if it is not loaded, the DOM tree will not be finished constructing, then the whole render tree will not construct. Why the elements like `<h1>` can be painted to the page if render tree is not constructed? In short words, why moving `<script>` to the end of `<body>` will make previous elements render on page?

Comment: `jQuery` doesn't block page rendering, but `doSomething` does. Page waits  while `while` cycle will be executed, and than load `jquery`. Add `async` attribute for your first script - and all will work as you expect

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I opened this page, and saw <h1> element appeared after the execution of doSomething.js. And if I removed jQuery, it appeared before the execution. That confused me.

Comment: because without `jQuery` your DOM structure is completed, it renders the page, and executes `doSomething`, and WITH jQuery - it has one more element in DOM (`<script>` tag), and can add it to the DOM only after `doSomething` execute.

Answer (score 0):

> Why jQuery blocks DOM rendering in my example?

`doSomething` appear to be blocking UI

> Why the elements like `<h1>` can be painted to the page if render tree
>   is not constructed?

Try using `$.holdReady()` , `$.Deferred()`

```css
body * {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <script>
    $.holdReady(true);

    function doSomething(n) {
      return new $.Deferred(function(d) {
        setTimeout(d.resolve, n * 1000)
      }).promise()
    }

    doSomething(5).then(function() {
      $.holdReady(false)
    });

    $(function() {
      $("body *").css("opacity", 1)
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>haha</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics" />
</body>
```